# Bitcoins stuck and showing as negative on block chain

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions

I sent money to a Bitcoin address which keeps changing on hourly by the time I sent the btc and it could get to the other end the address at the other end changed. Now the transaction is stuck somewhere I am not sure need your help to retrieve my lost btc

[image: bitcoin stuck]

Comment: Can you elaborate? Transaction 3bed5f667d64c4175893f93681816f5d47cb5a47f64831d8be4ff12dc619f7ab is confirmed, not stucked as you suggested.

Comment: The amount did not reach the other end showing in negative ... so how can I retrieve this back please suggest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sites which generate new addresses every hour always keep the old addresses too, so your bitcoins won't be lost. The second transaction which shows the amount as negative means that the bitcoins were then transferred out of the address shortly after you sent them. Looks like everything is as expected though.

Comment: Can you please suggest how can I retrieve the btc back to my wallet

Comment: You can't, if you sent it then you have to ask them for a refund (whoever you sent it to)